# Jenkins Pipeline Syntax - Need to get Parameters for Job from wget

Tags: bash, csv, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Im new to Jenkins Pipeline , Groovy syntax etc.

- I have a Jenkins job that takes **5 parameters**.
- I want to **schedule** a pipeline that checks for listings via **WGET** ( format is csv - i can switch to JSON output also ) and the csv is one row with 5 parameters listed
  a,b,c,d,e
- I need to parse that list and pass the parameters to the
  JOB "IF" there are rows , if not , skip and complete the pipeline.

I have searched and basically got as far as this for testing...:

```
pipeline {

environment {
 testVar='foo'}

agent any

stages {
    stage('Example Build') {

        steps {
            echo 'Hello World'

            script {

       sh "RESULT=\$(wget -qO- https://www.url.com/getlist)"
       sh "echo \$RESULT"
      //variable define based on parse of CSV???
    }

        }
    }
    stage('Example Deploy') {
        when {

            expression { testVar=='foo' }
        }
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying'
   build job: 'Testing', parameters: 
  [
  string(name: 's_e', value: 'u'),
  string(name: 't_e', value: 't'),
  string(name: 's_s', value: 'DS'),
  string(name: 't_s', value: 'SH'),
  string(name: 'efg', value: 'TEST')
  ]

        }
    }
}}
```

Obviously i have more work to do around parse of `RESULT` (but I am not sure how I can achieve this in Pipeline).

I then need to check for `RESULT` empty or not , then pass variables to the Build.

Comment: Could you please try: `def out = sh(script: 'wget -qO- https://www.url.com/getlist', returnStdout: true)` ?

Comment: Thanks Opal , where would be best to place that?

Comment: Try just after `echo Hello World`. Not sure if it works ;)

Comment: Have added after where i had RESULT defined and hasnt errored but a little unsure what to do with it next :)

Comment: `echo` it for instance. And if displays expected output go with parsing.

Comment: Thanks , had tried but not returning. I see your concept though of returning true if im getting values

Answer (score 1):

I opted for a different option.

Instead I now have a Jenkins Job where I use the "Trigger/Call Builds on other Projects"

Before thats added as a build step , i have some code to get the WGET CSV information.

```
RESULT=$(wget -qO- https://url.com/getlist)


if [ -z "$RESULT" ]
then

echo "Nothing to do"
# exit 1

else

echo "$RESULT"

s_env_upper=$(echo $RESULT | awk -F',' '{print $1}')
t_env_upper=$(echo $RESULT | awk -F',' '{print $2}')
s_env=$(echo $s_env_upper| tr [A-Z] [a-z])
t_env=$(echo $t_env_upper| tr [A-Z] [a-z])

echo "s_env=$s_env" > params.cfg
echo "t_env=$t_env" >> params.cfg


fi
```

[image: Build step showing read of the cfg file just created]

Hope this helps someone else... i was breaking my heart trying to get pipeline to do the work and answer was simpler.